# In Spring JPA how can we source our queries for XML file or bean.xml like ibatis?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a use case where I want my application to be more property driven and configurable so that any change in Database Column name would not affect the same.
Hence, In Spring JPA how can we source our queries for XML file or bean.xml like ibatis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of annotations JPA can use XML to do the mapping.

The default file name is `orm.xml` and if you add this file to the META-INF directory Spring Data JPA will load it by default.

You can also specify the file with a property:

```
spring.jpa.orm=orm.xml
```

The orm.xml has the same capability as the annotations.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm
                                     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd" version="2.1">

    <!-- JPA Named Native Queries -->
    <named-native-query name="Book.findAll" result-class="com.memorynotfound.hibernate.Book">
        <query>SELECT * FROM Book</query>
    </named-native-query>
    <named-native-query name="Book.findById" result-class="com.memorynotfound.hibernate.Book">
        <query>SELECT * FROM Book WHERE id = :id</query>
    </named-native-query>

    <!-- entity mapping -->
    <entity class="com.memorynotfound.hibernate.Book">
        <attributes>
            <basic name="title"/>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```

Find more about XML mapping in the official Hibernate documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-jpa-xml-files