# What is the best way to maintain queries in Spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra

In My Application, Using the below technologies

1. Spring boot 2.7.x
2. Cassandra
3. spring batch 5. x
4. java 11

As part of this, I need to extract data from the Cassandra database and need to write out the file
so here I need to use queries to fetch data so
just want to know what is the best way to maintain all queries at one place so any query changes come in the future, I shouldn't build the app rather just need to modify the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56555831/5525384

Answer (score 1):

Using a repository class is necessary. If you are using JPA i recommend using a repository for each Entity class. With JDBC it is possible to create a single repository which contains all the queries. To access the query methodes i would use a service class. In this way your code is structured well and maintainable for future changes.